Area of shaded portion
As shown in the diagram, CD = 5 cm, CF = 1 cm. O is the center of the semi-circle. Find the area of the green shaded part.
I may only use Pythagoras theorem or similarity to solve this problem but no using of trigonometry.
I have tried as follows:
1). Draw a line joining O to D and a line joining O to E. These two lines will be perpendicular to the AC and AB respectively.
2). Let FO be x cm.
3). Using Pythagoras theorem on right triangle DOC, forming $x^2$ + $5^2$ = $(x+1)^2$. I solve for x which turns out to be 12.
4). I have identified triangle ADO and triangle AEO are congruent since DO = EO, AO is a common side for both triangles and both triangles are right triangles. Therefore, AD = AE.
I am stuck here and am not sure how to continue. Your help is appreciated.


There is no way to get that Area , which is variable , according to where Point $E$ is.

Note that there are 2 F's in the diagram.

Your issue hasn't a solution because the green area hasn't a fixed value.
A main feature of the figure is that circle with center $O$ is fixed. Indeed, reasoning on the power of point $C$ with respect to this circle gives $CD^2=CF.CF'$ from which one deduces that $CF' = 25$ which means that $F$ is fixed ; therefore the circle is fixed.
As $A$ can be taken anywhere on line $CD$, it can be taken in particular at the intersection of side $CD$ with the upper horizontal tangent to the circle : in this case, point $B$
is sent to infinity, and the green area becomes ... infinite...


thank you all for the explanation and contributions. I really appreciate it. The figure may have some missing information. No wonder I am not able to solve it.

Maybe there the angle in $A$ is given somewhere ?...
